# UITouch issue with Swift 2.0, XCode 7, ios9 and new iPhone 6S

Tags: iphone, swift2, ios9, xcode7, uitouch

I recently updated my SpriteKit game to iOS9 with XCode7 and Swift 2.0 and am running on a new iPhone 6s.  Using the code below.  The issue is that the first touch is registered, but no subsequent touches are recognized.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
  for touch in (touches ) {
    print(touch)
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    //Other code
  }
}
```

I'm also getting the error   `<CAMetalLayer: 0x12ed24bb0>: calling -display has no effect.` when I first run the SKScene.  Not sure that's related to my issue though.

Any ideas for how to get multiple touches working again?  I'm going to test with my old iPhone 5S later to see if it's a problem with iPhone 6S or with iOS9/XC7/Swift2.0.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is adding `self.view?.multipleTouchEnabled = true` to `didMoveToView(view: SKView)`

Hopefully this saves others the headache it caused me!

Comment: To clarify, I'm still getting the `<CAMetalLayer: 0x157b26000>: calling -display has no effect.` error.  So that was unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

There is some modification in UITouch class methods for **iPhone 6s** and **iPhone 6s plus**

> so you need to call the base class methods for every touch method you override like:

Example-

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

       // Other Code
    }
```